# Find keywords from txt files and copy target files

Tags: python

I have some textfiles in a folder and I want to search all of them for names between row 4 and 20 and then copy the ones containing one of those names to a different folder. With my code I only get an empty result file even though I know the keywords are in my folder. What could be the problem with this code for Python 3?

```
from os import system, listdir, path
import codecs
FILE = open('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Test\\Result.txt', 'w') 
desktop_dir = path.join('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\test\\')  
for fn in listdir(desktop_dir):
    fn_w_path = path.join(desktop_dir, fn)
    if path.isfile(fn_w_path):
        with open(fn_w_path, "r") as filee:  
            for line in filee.readlines():  
                for word in line.lower().split():
                    if word in {'James',
                                'Tim',
                                'Tom',
                                'Ian',
                                'William',
                                'Dennis',}:  
                        FILE.write(word + "\n")
FILE.close()

import os
import shutil

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("test_dir1", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        current_file = os.path.join(root, name)
        destination = current_file.replace("test_dir1", "test_dir2")
        print("Found file: %s" % current_file)
        print("File copy to: %s" % destination)
        shutil.copy(current_file, destination)
```

Comment: You converted to lower case and check with Title case words. How does that suppose to work?

Comment: Just a hint: calling `line.lower().split()` means that the result cannot possibly match anything in that set. james != James

Comment: Oh thank you, so simple! Anyhow the files with those words are not copied, what could be the problem?

Comment: Also I get error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2064". I guess it has something to do with the codec? How can I solve that?